# How can I add a shadow to a custom title style?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I'm currently writing down a few things for an RPG conversion using Word 2013.

I'm a bit stuck trying to create my own heading style. The heading style should have a specific color and shadow. Also, I want the paragraph that follows to return using standard text style automatically.

Whenever I use my style, "Nachteil", I don't get the shadow below text; I get what you see in the first line in the figure below. However, the style "Hervorhe" (which might translate as "emphasis" or "highlighting")
gives me what I want, as illustrated in the second line.

**Figure (1) First line is what I get, second line is what I want:**
[image: 1st line is what I got, 2nd line what I wanted]

**Figure (2) Here is the format of style "Nachteil":**
[image: The format of the template]

**Figure (3) And here is the list of available styles in the Ribbon, including "Hervorhe":**
[image: Toolbar]

So I get the shadow below text that I desire only when I apply style "Hervorhe" from the list of styles.

My question here is: What can I do to make my style "Nachteil" look like the second line in Figure (1) above AND at the same time switch to a standard style when I start a new paragraph with <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly you've tried. "When I try it" - what? "Only when I also add "highlighting"" - how did you add it? Please include also some screenshots from the settings of the different examples.

Comment: I added it by clicking on highlight in the toolbar in addition to the title. Only then did I get the second look

Comment: You offered 50 reputation for this question, but don't have time to properly edit your question, why???

Comment: @MátéJuhász I didn't edit back 1 hour ago as I just came home from work and had 2 hours of sleep today so my concentration was zero (just enough to do a fast reply as comment and take a while to get together screenshots to edit the post ;)   That aside during the screenshot taking I found a strange change that I added as "Edit" at the end of the question.

Comment: What happens if you edit "Hervorhe" and change "next paragraph" to normal?

Comment: @MátéJuhász you mean if I select "Hervorhe..." and then try to change the next paragraph to normal? (then I need to remove all text formats for the line manually as else "hervorhe..." stays as I can't unselect it (hervorhe is "highlight" in the english word version)). Did you mean that or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38000/discussion-between-mate-juhasz-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer the topic's title and the question that ended with. Feel free to comment if I didn't cover your question. **Tell me if I did understand what you want so I may edit you question to be clear for the rest of people**

Assuming you want to edit a style to have some shadow, and that style is called `Nachteil`. Since I don't use German Microsoft Word, I'll use your screenshots when possible, otherwise I'll use the English commands.

Open the dialogue box `Formatvorlage ändern` to modify your style `Nachteil`. That's from right-clicking the style from the style pane `Formatvorlage` (screenshot 2) on the Ribbon and choosing `ändern`.

From the dialogue box (screenshot 1), look at the bottom and click the button `Format`, then choose `Text Effects` from the pop-up menu (I don't know it in German but it's the last command in that menu).

From the new dialogue box, click the second `A` button. Expand the first command (English: `Shadow`). Choose a colour (button 2) and set your other preferences regarding size and angle. Click `OK` to confirm your changes.

Now returning to the dialogue box `Formatvorlage ändern`, if you want to change the style for the next paragraph (when pressing key Enter) to style `Normal` or any other style you prefer, choose it from the menu `Formatvorlage für folgenden Absatz:`. Click `OK` to confirm your changes.

**Note:** This procedure will change every text's appearance using style `Nachteil`. However, changing the next paragraph's style from `Nachteil` is only effective to the edits after doing the above procedure. Existing paragraphs following texts that applied style `Nachteil` previously will have no effect in this regard.

Comment: Hi tnx will accept this as its a good tutorial there. What I found btw is that it seems that at least my word is sometimes buggy there (Nachteil not ending and returning to standard, or parts of Nachteils format being ignored until I delete those lines and write them anew,...). Maybe a bit of warning to those trying to so such things, that it seems like word is a bit buggy in these regards (or its just my pc again....got a bit of bad luck there^^')

Comment: @Thomas You're welcome :) While Word is a powerful and friendly programme, it becomes stubborn if you don't do things as Word likes it. Copy Nachteils texts and paste them as plain texts (Ribbon \ `Home` \ arrow under `Paste` \ first button from right captioned `Keep text only`). Select this pasted text and apply style Nachteils. Now when you hit key `Enter` at the end of line, it should change style to `Normal`, hopefully.